# convert lowercase to uppercase first character and make other chars stay lower

Tags: c++

```
 void correcter(string s, int j)
{
    string correct;
    for (; j < s.length(); j++)
    {
        if (int(s[j]) != 46){
            if (int(s[j]) >= 97 && int(s[j]) <= 122 && i == 0)
            {
                char a = int(s[j]) - 32;
                correct += a;
                i++;
            }
            else if (int(s[j]) >= 65 && int(s[j]) <= 90&&i==0)
            {
                char a = int(s[j]) + 32;
                correct += a;
                i++;
            }
            else if (int(s[j]) >= 65 && int(s[j]) <= 90)
            {
                char a = int(s[j]) + 32;
                correct += a;
                i++;

            }
            else
                correct += s[j];
        }
        else
        {
            correct += ". ";
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << correct << endl;
}
```

question is to write a code that convert first character of string to uppercase and other stay as lowercase. after every "." make the words first char again upper and other parts in lower!

Input:

> hellOWOrLD.hELLOWORLD.

Output:

> Helloworld. Helloworld.

It should work like in the picture...

[image]

Comment: What's your question? FYI: Have a look at `std::tolower` and `std::toupper`.

Comment: well it can convert only firs or all  characters mine is to convert its first character plus to make other part of the word in lowercase as in example  input=> hellOWOrLD.hELLOWORLD. output=>Helloworld. Helloworld.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `isalpha()`, `toupper()` and `tolower()`

EDIT:  To look for punctuation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void upperCase(string& line)  {
    bool firstCharacter = true;
    string punctuation=".?!";

    for(int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      char c=line[i];
        if(isalpha(c)) {
            if (firstCharacter) {
                line[i] = toupper(c);
                firstCharacter = false;
            } else {
                line[i] = tolower(c);
            }
        } else if (punctuation.find(c)!=string::npos) {
          firstCharacter=true;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    string str = "hello UNiverse?! World? Hello. Hello";
    upperCase(str);
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

Comment: how about ". " if there are some it should seperate with some blank spaces and then make another words first letter in uppercase

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it is , exactly woooow yahooo thank u Paul Bentley

Comment: not sure - I think you have to accept it?  I have not asked a question here yet.